# Can't center button group in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know a css lib in bootstrap for centering a group of buttons?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" class="nav navbar-nav " role="tablist">
    <div class="center-block" class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">7ا</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">9</button>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `text-center` to the parent element

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/fL8lefeqTa)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" class="nav navbar-nav " role="tablist">
    <div class="text-center" class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">7ا</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">9</button>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Your markup is invalid however. You have two class declarations on the same element. The second will be ignored. Also, the only valid direct descendant elements for a `ul` are `li`s